# Django display different column from ForeignKey conditionally

Tags: python, django

I am implementing translation in my Django project. Last thing left for translation is translating category name, which is different model connected by foreign key.

My models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_pl = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='none')
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"


class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='note', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    note_text = models.TextField()
    add_date = models.DateTimeField('added date', auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=7)
    edit_dates = ArrayField(
        models.DateTimeField('edit dates', blank=True, null=True),
        default=list,
    )
    members = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=200)
    )
    allow_edits = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In Category model is field name, which is an english name of category and field name_pl - polish name of category.

My form:

```
class AddNewNote(forms.ModelForm):
    file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={
        'multiple': True, 'style': 'font-size: 22px;'}
    ), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ['title', 'note_text', 'category', ]
        widgets = {
            'category': forms.Select(attrs={'style': 'font-size: 22px;'}),
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'font-size: 22px;'}),
            'note_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'style': 'font-size: 22px;'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddNewNote, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['file_field'].label = _("Files")
        self.fields['title'].label = _("Title")
        self.fields['note_text'].label = _("Note text")
        self.fields['category'].label = _("Category")
```

I am translating form labels using gettext_lazy, but I have no idea how to use different Category field in case of language.
I know that there is a function `get_language()` so I could do something like that:

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language

if get_language() == 'en':
    fields = ['title', 'note_text', 'category.name',]
elif get_language() == 'pl':
    fields = ['title', 'note_text', 'category.name_pl',]
```

But that obviously not working. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was easier than I thought. All I had to do was check language in `models.py` and return correct field.

```
def __str__(self):
    lang = get_language()

    if lang == 'en':
        return self.name
    elif lang == 'pl':
        return self.name_pl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the language to your form from your view with something like;

```
form = AddNewNote(language=get_language())
```

Then you can get that value in the form and modify the fields loaded;

```
class AddNewNote(forms.ModelForm):
    file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={
        'multiple': True, 'style': 'font-size: 22px;'}
    ), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ['title', 'note_text', 'category', ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        language = kwargs.get("language")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if language == 'en':
            self.fields.pop("title")
```

However what you can't do, is what you're trying to do with fields on the related model in your form for `Note`.

You need a form for each model instance you want to modify. So you need an inline form for the `Category` instance that you want to modify. This gets a bit more complicated, but the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) are the best place to start.